# Qt program ignores KDE theme and qtconfig theme

Tags: qt

When I run my Qt5 program as a superuser, the program completely ignores any system fonts, themes and icons and uses some bogus theme. See screenshot.

HOW to fix this programmatically or in any way possible??

It also ignores any KDE configs/qtconfig. This is driving me nuts.

[image]

Right is run as normal user, left is run as superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Your config is being saved in your **user's home**. If you open app as root, it is working with root's settings. Easiest way to fix this would be graphical root login, than change settings to what you want and switch back to regular user. Root graphical login is disabled in most distros but you can still do it by using second terminal.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open a second terminal.

Login as **root** (password won't appear).

Type `startx` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the GUI should start automatically.

Go for `settings`, set whatever theme you want, then log out.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go back to first terminal.

Everything should look nice from now on.